# Pretty print ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, code-formatting, pretty-print

Some tools output an Antlr grammar in a human-unreadable form, at least with ugly placing of parens and indentation.  I'd like to transform the grammar into a more readable (standard?) form.  The only reference I found is [ANTLR pretty printer](http://www.antlr.org/share/list) which is quite old, and looking at its source, it seems to be removing parts of a grammar rather than pretty print it.

How can I format/pretty print a grammar file?

Comment: So … you got a question?

Comment: I added my question: how to format/pretty print a grammar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed an [Antlr plugin for Eclipse](http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/).  It can do a lot more than syntax highlight and code formatting...

Comment: You mean it does grammar-pretty-printing? Cool, didn't know.

Comment: It does.  And it promises many things I don't need at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I know of no tool that does this. The one you mentioned, `prettyPrinter`, is written in - and seems to handle only - ANTLR v2.x grammars, making it unsuitable for v3 grammars.

If you're going to write your own, I'd recommend using the grammar of ANTLR v3 itself to parse a `.g` grammar file and emit it in a readable form. Terence Parr has posted the grammar here: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/ANTLR

Comment: thanks for the idea. I don't feel like parsing a grammar file myself :)

Comment: Be warned, though, that this is not the real ANTLR grammar, there are some subtle differences. An otherwise valid grammar that it doesn't parse is `grammar G; options {output=AST;} a : '1' ('+'|'-')^ '1';`.

Comment: Indeed, it trips over the `^`... I hadn't expected that! Thanks for the heads up @Gunther!